# Creating new directories by iterating through specified dataframe values Python Pandas Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, operating-system

I am trying to create folders by reading each row from specific columns in a dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

raw_df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/home/Desktop/test/Inventory.xls')
df = raw_df[["Barcode", "Brand", "product_name"]]
```

raw_df: [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJRu2.png)

df: [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKNFM.png)

> My current working directory: C:\Users\home\Desktop\test\

```
path = os.getcwd()
new_path = os.chdir(path + "\\products\\")

print ("The new working directory is %s" % os.getcwd())
```

> The new working directory is C:\Users\home\Desktop\test\products\

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    row = df.iloc[i]
    barcode = row["Barcode"]
    brand = row["Brand"]
    product_name = row["Product_Name"]
    if(("\\" + barcode + "\\__" + brand + "\\__" + product_name + "\\") == False):
        os.makedir("\\" + barcode + "\\__" + brand + "\\__" + product_name + "\\")
    else:
        print("failed")
```

My output:

> failed
>   failed
>   failed
>   failed
>   failed
>   failed

I have over 400 rows in the raw df, I was just testing it for the first 6 rows.

What I am trying to achieve is as follows: [End Result snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuA7T.png)

so i am trying to take each row and using them to create a new directory, seperated by double underscores "__".

Additional note: I have deleted the folders from the working directory (the ones I created myself) and ran the code above and have still not attained the results I was after.

I Would have created a bash script, but that is not an options as I will need to populate these folders with various data such as images etc as I iterate through the dataframe.

any help would be greatly appreciated. I will continue to work on this and report back with a solution for everyones benefit if I am able to crack this.

Many Thanks,

Comment: with `if(("\\" + barcode + "\\__" + brand + "\\__" + product_name + "\\") == False)` you are comparing a string to False. It's not a way of checking if the directory exists

Comment: Try `os.path.exists(path)` or `os.path.isdir(path)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `os.path.join` and `os.path.isdir`:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    row = df.iloc[i]
    barcode = row["Barcode"]
    brand = row["Brand"]
    product_name = row["Product_Name"]
    mypath = os.path.join(new_path, barcode, "__" + brand, "__" + product_name)
    if (os.path.isdir(mypath)):
        print("failed")
    else:
        os.mkdir(mypath)
```

Comment: @JameBlonde try printing brand, its probably empty

Answer (score 0):

@vercelli, Thank you for all your help and pointing me in the right direction, I have managed to get the following code working:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    row = df.iloc[i]
    barcode = row["Barcode"]
    brand = row["Brand"]
    product_name = row["Product_Name"]

    mypath = os.getcwd() + "\\" + barcode + "__" + brand + "__" + product_name + "\\"

    if(os.path.isdir(path) == False):
        os.mkdir(path)
    else:
        print("failed")
```

as mentioned by @vercelli, make sure your dataframe does not contain any of the values in its field:

> /:*?"<>|

as these are invalid characters for creating directories, I'm not too familiar with other systems, but windows certainly does not accept those characters for creating the directories with those values.